# Can not validate if textfield is empty

Tags: ios, swift

I am posting this after having tried all the `.isEmpty` solutions i found.

I am unable to detect a value in textField. I have cells which are set to `cell.selectionStyle = .none`. These cells have a `label` and `textFields`.

I have given the cells identifiers:

```swift
let cell = addRestaurant.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: String(describing: RestaurantAddViewCells.self), for: indexPath) as! RestaurantAddViewCells
```

My goal is to have a button which checks if any field is empty onclick.

```swift
let saveButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "save"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(saveRestaurant))
```

Here is how i try to check if the textFields are empty or not:

```swift
@objc func saveRestaurant() {
    if let indexPath = addRestaurant.indexPathForSelectedRow {   
        let cell = addRestaurant.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! RestaurantAddViewCells
        if (cell.nameTextField.text == "" || cell.typeTextField.text == "" || cell.locationTextField.text == "" || cell.hotelPhoneText.text == "") {
            let saveAlertController = UIAlertController(title: "Fields Empty", message: "fill all fields", preferredStyle: .alert)
            let saveAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
            saveAlertController.addAction(saveAction)
            self.present(saveAlertController, animated: false, completion: nil)
        }
        else { }
    }
}
```

However nothing happens

I have tried and comment `cell.selectionStyle = .none`, still no effect

Here `addRestaurant` is tableView in same file while `RestaurantAddViewCells` is a class containing properties for `labels` , `textFields`

UPDATE - here is what i do in my cellForRowAt, sample for first two cells

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        switch indexPath.row {
        case 0:
            let cell = addRestaurant.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: String(describing: RestaurantAddViewCells.self), for: indexPath) as! RestaurantAddViewCells
            view.addSubview(cell.contentView)
            view.addSubview(cell.hotelImage)
            view.addSubview(cell.imageButton)
            view.addSubview(cell)
            
            cell.imageButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            cell.hotelImage.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            //set the cell height
            cell.heightAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualToConstant: 200).isActive = true
            
            //set the hotelImage
            
            cell.hotelImage.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: UIScreen.main.bounds.width).isActive = true
            cell.hotelImage.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true
            
            
            cell.hotelImage.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
            cell.hotelImage.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.topAnchor).isActive = true
            
            // pin it
            //No need to pin it as width is already pinned to to lead and trail of screen
            cell.imageButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true
            cell.imageButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true
            
            cell.imageButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
            cell.imageButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
            cell.imageButton.image = UIImage(named: "photo")
            
            return cell
            
        case 1:
            let cell = addRestaurant.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: String(describing: RestaurantAddViewCells.self), for: indexPath) as! RestaurantAddViewCells
            
            cell.nameTextFiled.tag = 1
            cell.nameTextFiled.delegate = self
            cell.nameTextFiled.becomeFirstResponder()
            cell.selectionStyle = .none
            cell.heightAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualToConstant: 100).isActive = true
            view.addSubview(cell.nameLabel)
            view.addSubview(cell.nameTextFiled)
            view.addSubview(cell)
            view.addSubview(cell.contentView)
            cell.nameLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            cell.nameTextFiled.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            cell.nameTextFiled.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
            cell.nameLabel.text = "Name:"
            
            
            
            //Define custom fonts
            
            let font = UIFont(name: "Rubik-Medium", size: 18)
            let dynamicFonts = UIFontMetrics(forTextStyle: .body)
            cell.nameLabel.font = dynamicFonts.scaledFont(for: font!)
            cell.nameTextFiled.font = dynamicFonts.scaledFont(for: font!)
            cell.nameTextFiled.borderStyle = .roundedRect
            cell.nameTextFiled.placeholder = "Enter Your Name"
            
            
            
            let stackName = UIStackView()
            view.addSubview(stackName)
            stackName.alignment = .top
            stackName.axis = .vertical
            stackName.spacing = 5.0
            stackName.distribution = .fill
            stackName.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            stackName.addArrangedSubview(cell.nameLabel)
            stackName.addArrangedSubview(cell.nameTextFiled)
            
            
            
            stackName.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.topAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
            stackName.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.leadingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
            stackName.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.trailingAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
            
            cell.nameTextFiled.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stackName.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
            
            return cell
```

This is what my updated RestaurantAddViewCells lookslike with input from one member here

```
class RestaurantAddViewCells: UITableViewCell, UITextFieldDelegate, UITextViewDelegate {
    
    var nameLabel: UILabel = UILabel()
    var nameTextFiled: RoundedTextFields = RoundedTextFields()
    
    var typeLabel: UILabel = UILabel()
    var typeTextField: RoundedTextFields = RoundedTextFields()
    
    var locationLabel: UILabel = UILabel()
    var locationTextField: RoundedTextFields = RoundedTextFields()
    
    var imageButton: UIImageView = UIImageView()
    var hotelImage: UIImageView = UIImageView()
    
    var hotelDescriptionLabel: UILabel = UILabel()
    var hotelTextDescription: UITextView = UITextView()
    
    var hotelPhonelabel: UILabel = UILabel()
    var hotelPhoneText: RoundedTextFields = RoundedTextFields()
    
    
    var isEmptyTextFields: Bool {
        return nameTextFiled.text!.isEmpty || typeTextField.text!.isEmpty || locationTextField.text!.isEmpty || hotelTextDescription.text!.isEmpty || hotelPhoneText.text!.isEmpty
    }
    

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }
    
    
    

}
```

UPDATE 2 - so here is my update while trying to ask the question again, i have a `tableview` where each cell has some `textfields`, when i press a button before i do any thing with the data, i want to check if the fields are filled or not, how can i do this, now as per my design i use a class to define the view properties and call them and give then values where i use the tableView, i use `cellForRowAt` to define constraints and provide values to labels etc, but how can i successfully access them outside of `cellForRowAt` to check current state , with out totally changing the design of project

UPDATE 3 - it seems if i were to do the same thing in story board and add the outlets to same function it is capable of detecting a change in state of textbox, if it is empty or not, in case of trying to do it programatically, its not able to detect a change in state of textbox from empty to not empty, but i still have no way to check like in javascript if the textboxes are empty or not on button click

Update 4 - I am now using below code on button tap, but for some strange reason , i am not able to detect the text entered, it always keeps returning empty even if there is text there

```
@objc func saveRestaurant(sender: AnyObject) {
        
        let cell = addRestaurant.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: String(describing: RestaurantAddViewCells.self)) as! RestaurantAddViewCells
        
        if cell.nameTextFiled.text == "" || cell.typeTextField.text == "" || cell.locationTextField.text == "" || cell.hotelPhoneText.text == "" || cell.hotelTextDescription.text == "" {
                let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Oops", message: "We can't proceed because one of the fields is blank. Please note that all fields are required.", preferredStyle: .alert)
                let alertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil)
                alertController.addAction(alertAction)
                present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
           // addRestaurant.reloadData()
                return
            }
        
        else {
            
            print("Name: \(cell.nameTextFiled.text ?? "")")
            print("Type: \(cell.typeTextField.text ?? "")")
            print("Location: \(cell.locationTextField.text ?? "")")
            print("Phone: \(cell.hotelPhoneText.text ?? "")")
            print("Description: \(cell.hotelTextDescription.text ?? "")")
            
            dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
     
    }
```

Update 5 - this is what has finally worked , but is very long and not so good, can any one suggest a loop for going through all the indexPath

```
  @objc func saveRestaurant(sender: AnyObject) {

        let index = IndexPath(row: 1, section: 0)
        let cell: RestaurantAddViewCells = self.addRestaurant.cellForRow(at: index) as! RestaurantAddViewCells
        let nameVal = cell.nameTextFiled.text!
        
        let index1 = IndexPath(row: 2, section: 0)
        let cell2: RestaurantAddViewCells = self.addRestaurant.cellForRow(at: index1) as! RestaurantAddViewCells
        let typeVal = cell2.typeTextField.text!
        
        let index2 = IndexPath(row: 3, section: 0)
        let cell3: RestaurantAddViewCells = self.addRestaurant.cellForRow(at: index2) as! RestaurantAddViewCells
        let locationVal = cell3.locationTextField.text!
        
        let index3 = IndexPath(row: 4, section: 0)
        let cell4: RestaurantAddViewCells = self.addRestaurant.cellForRow(at: index3) as! RestaurantAddViewCells
        let phoneVal = cell4.hotelPhoneText.text!
        
        let index4 = IndexPath(row: 5, section: 0)
        let cell5: RestaurantAddViewCells = self.addRestaurant.cellForRow(at: index4) as! RestaurantAddViewCells
        let descVal = cell5.hotelTextDescription.text!
        
        if(nameVal == "" || typeVal == "" || locationVal == "" || phoneVal == "" || descVal == "") {
            let saveAlertController = UIAlertController(title: "Fields Empty", message: "fill all fields", preferredStyle: .alert)
            let saveAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
            saveAlertController.addAction(saveAction)
            self.present(saveAlertController, animated: false, completion: nil)
            //  return
        }
        else {
            
            print("Name: \(nameVal)")
            print("Type: \(typeVal)")
            print("Location: \(locationVal)")
            print("Phone: \(phoneVal)")
            print("Description: \(descVal)")
            self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: false)
            
        }
 
    }
```

Comment: To rephrase this so i understand. You have a tableView with each cell having textfields and a label. If you click the BarButton, you want to check which textfields? Of all cells?

Comment: Can you be more specific? how are you selecting tableview cell, if you're not selecting table cell programmatically, `addRestaurant.indexPathForSelectedRow` will always give you nil. To be more specific if your textfield gets activated when you tap on it, it doesn't mean your tableview cell is selected. Please post your code so that people here can help you out

Comment: @Deitsch - thanks, i want to find if they are empty , even if one of them is empty the alert should show

Comment: Ok, after your replay to previous user's question, I'll try to answer your question below

Comment: @PratikJamariya - thanks, yes you are right that is where the problem is , i am not sure if  if let indexPath = addRestaurant.indexPathForSelectedRow, will work as the cells do not get selected, and i want the button to respond even if users , presses it with out going inside the textfilelds, how do i access these textfileds which where created using deque method ?

Comment: How many cells do you have in the tableView?

Comment: @multiverse I have answered below, I kept it as easy as I could for better understanding

Comment: @PGDev - six cells, static all declared inside cellForRowAt, with labels and texts being created using properties in another class RestaurantAddViewCells, my problem is how do i access these cells once i am outside the cellForRowAt method

Comment: @multiverse I have edited my answer according to your needs. Feel free to ask questions if you have any

Comment: @PratikJamariya - I have made an update 5, here the code now does exactly as i want check for nil fields, but it need to individually add the indexPath, very long method, can you please suggest how i can loop through it , thanks for your help

Comment: @PGDev - can you please suggest on update 5 , how i can shorten the code its very long and repetitive , thanks for your help

Comment: @multiverse Is the issue resolved? Because I don't think you're doing it right. So many textFields in RestaurantAddViewCells are not required.

Comment: @PGDev, the issue is not there, but i will need to learn to code better in swift, still early days

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to give you an answer as easy as I can make possible.

**Problem**

You're using a table view and it's cell which contains a textfield where user may enter some input, also the cell may get reused when scrolled and its possible we may lose input from user.

**Solution**

We have a textfield in our cells, and we need all the inputs from user to be stored somewhere lets say a dictionary of `IndexPath` as key and `String` as value. Something like `var inputs:[IndexPath: String] = [:]`. Whenever user enters something and as soon as leaves the textfield we'll store that input in our dictionary against it's cell indexPath. when user clicks on button, we'll loop through and check which textfield is empty

A very simple example is here

```
import UIKit

class TextFieldTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    lazy var textField: UITextField = {
        let textField = UITextField()
        textField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        textField.placeholder = "Enter your text here"
        return textField
    } ()
    lazy var label: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.setContentHuggingPriority(.required, for: .horizontal)
        return label
    }()

    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        self.setupView()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

}

extension TextFieldTableViewCell {

    //MARK: Private
    private func setupView() {
        selectionStyle = .none
        contentView.addSubview(label)
        contentView.addSubview(textField)
        label.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 8).isActive = true
        label.topAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 8).isActive = true
        label.bottomAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: -8).isActive = true
        label.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true

        textField.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: label.trailingAnchor, constant: 8).isActive = true
        textField.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -8).isActive = true
        textField.topAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 8).isActive = true
        textField.bottomAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: -8).isActive = true
        textField.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true

    }

}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    private lazy var tableView: UITableView = {
        let tableView = UITableView.init(frame: .zero, style: .grouped)
        tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return tableView
    }()

    private var inputs: [IndexPath: String] = [:]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.addSubview(tableView)
        tableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        tableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.register(TextFieldTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "TextFieldTableViewCell")
        title = "Some random title"
        let barbutton = UIBarButtonItem.init(barButtonSystemItem: .done, target: self, action: #selector(saveAction(_:)))
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barbutton
    }

    @objc
    func saveAction(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        view.endEditing(true)
        for i in 0 ..< tableView.numberOfSections {
            for j in 0 ..< tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: i) {
                let indexPath = IndexPath.init(row: j, section: i)
                print("Input at indexPath: Row: \(indexPath.row), Section: \(indexPath.section)")
                if let input = inputs[indexPath], input.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines).count > 0 {
                    print(input)
                }
                else {
                    print("user has not input any value or kept it empty")
                }
                print("__________")
            }
        }
    }


}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        30
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TextFieldTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as? TextFieldTableViewCell ?? TextFieldTableViewCell.init(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "TextFieldTableViewCell")
        cell.label.text = "Row: \(indexPath.row)"
        cell.textField.delegate = self
        cell.textField.text = inputs[indexPath]
        return cell
    }

}

extension ViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {
    func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        if let cell = textField.superview?.superview as? TextFieldTableViewCell, let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: cell) {
            inputs[indexPath] = textField.text
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

After OPs comments, here's the solution that will work for OP

Solution:
As OP has only 6 cells, we can cache then in a dictionary and return from the dictionary whenever needed. (We're doing this only because of small number of table cells and OP's structure. I do not recommend this solution)

Add a new dictionary to your viewcontroller

```
private var cachedCell: [IndexPath: TextFieldTableViewCell] = [:]
```

Change Cell for row to this (Note that you should not reuse tableview cell as we're caching them in our cachedCell dictionary otherwise it may result in unknown. It is never recommended to cache cells by me as well as other developers)

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if let cell = cachedCell[indexPath] {
        return cell
    }
    let cell = TextFieldTableViewCell.init(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "TextFieldTableViewCell")
    cell.label.text = "Row: \(indexPath.row)"
    cell.textField.delegate = self
    cell.textField.text = inputs[indexPath]
    cachedCell[indexPath] = cell
    return cell
}
```

Change Save Action to

```
@objc
func saveAction(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    view.endEditing(true)
    for (indexPath, cell) in cachedCell {
        print("Input at indexPath: Row: \(indexPath.row), Section: \(indexPath.section)")
        if let input = cell.textField.text, input.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines).count > 0 {
            print(input)
        }
        else {
            print("user has not input any value or kept it empty")
        }
        print("__________")
    }
}
```

If you have any other questions, you can ask it in comment section.

**Happy Coding**

Comment: thanks a lot , but the problem is , i already have a different structure laid out for my project and every thing else is working, i need to validate, the fields, with out making all the changes you suggest, is there any way we can detect if a textFiled has any value or not

Comment: I can not tell without knowing your structure. And also, if your cell is recycled its likely to lose inputs of the text field.

Comment: i have updated the code in the cells i create and the class from which i use properties to create labels and texts

Answer (score 0):

First of all, add a **computed property** in `RestaurantAddViewCells` that'll return if any of the `textFields` in the `cell` is empty, i.e.

```
class RestaurantAddViewCells: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var nameTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var typeTextField: UITextField!
    
    var isEmptyTextFields: Bool {
        return nameTextField.text!.isEmpty || typeTextField.text!.isEmpty
    }
}
```

Now, your `saveRestaurant()` method will loop through the `numberOfCells`. Get the `cell` for each `row` and check if `isEmptyTextFields` returns `true`. In that case you need to show the `alert`.

```
@objc func saveRestaurant() {
    let numberOfCells = 6
    var isAnyTextFieldEmpty = false
    
    (0..<numberOfCells).forEach {
        let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: $0, section: 0)) as! RestaurantAddViewCells
        isAnyTextFieldEmpty = isAnyTextFieldEmpty || cell.isEmptyTextFields
    }
    
    if isAnyTextFieldEmpty {
        //Show alert...
    } else {
        //....
    }
}
```

Comment: ,thanks a lot,  i have added the code i am using , added your code , but just keeps getting the alert that i would get if the textfield were empty , seems i am not able to detect when text is filled in textfields

Comment: Couldn't get you.

Comment: now even if i enter the text in text fields , the alert or a simple message that says field is empty keeps showing up

Comment: @PGDev Your solution may seem to work but in case of reused cells, its behaviour may give is unknown results. Its is most likely to happen when user is using his phone in landscape cells may get reused

Comment: @PGDev, i must be doing something wrong, its not working, i use the first cell to upload an image and i do not still send the info to be saved yet, so at this time i am just checking if the user has filled all the fields, the way we do in javascript validations, i always keep getting empty alerts, every thing works this far but this textfield validations is not working